# 301 redirect rule through htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to `301` redirect from

`domain.com/?test-article.php`

to

`domain.com/full-article/test-article.php`

Here is my code what i am trying to use and its not working.

```
redirect 301 /?test-article.php http://domain.com/full-article/test-article.php
```

or

```
rewriteRule /?test-article.php http://domain.com/full-article/test-article.php [R=301,L]
```

if i use without '?' then it re-directs from

`/test-article.php`

to

```
http://domain.com/full-article/test-article.php
```

So something has to do with '?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string using a pattern of a `Redirect` or `RewriteRule`. You need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable and mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test-article$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.com/full-article/test-article.php [R=301,L]
```